# Stripping Phone Numbers of Non-numeric Values During SQL Query in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of new restaurants and I want to check them against a database of restaurants using the phone number. The problem with phone numbers is that they have different formatting in the database (i.e. `123-345-6789` or `(123)-456 8988`).

So far, I have created an index for the phone so that I search through them quickly. I also stripped the phone number of the new restaurants so that they only contain numeric values (0-9).

Now, I want to strip the databases' numbers right before I compare so that I will strictly comparing numbers.

```
#strip the phone of non-numeric values and spaces
formatted_phone = SunspotHelper.sanitize_term(pr.phone).gsub(/\s+/, "") 

Restaurant.where(contact_phone: formatted_phone).each do |r|
  #irrelevant code here
end
```

The problem with the above code is that contact_phone (from database) will be in its non-stripped format. My research so far has lead me to believe that I have to use something like `REGEXP_LIKE`, but I'm not quite sure how to implement this with Rails. I do NOT want to update the database - I simply want to strip the numbers for comparison while still keeping the original formatting in the DB.

How do I strip the phone numbers, `contact_phone`, of non-numeric values from the database before I compare it with `formatted_phone`?

Comment: You could create a new field in the database that carries the unformatted value of the contact_phone (while keeping the original)

Comment: @tamersalama Yeah, but that would mean that I'd have duplicate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd just like to limit your effort to the Rails query (instead of properly formatting the phone numbers in another field in the database) here's how you could use your DB engine's REGEXP capabilities

```
Restaurant.where(["REGEXP_REPLACE(contact_phone, '[^[:digit:]]', '') = ?", formatted_phone]).each do |r|
  #irrelevant code here
end
```

Comment: The REGEXP_REPLACE will not work in all engines (the example is showing an oracle function). I don't think MySQL has a built-in REGEXP_REPLACE function.

Comment: I was just testing this out and I keep getting the error REGEXP_REPLACE does not exist - as you've pointed out in your comment. Any tip on how I can fix this?

Comment: I looked into this some more. Looks like there is no easy implementation with MySQL. Furthermore, doing it this way, I still have to iterate through each record. In a database of several hundred thousand, this is too slow. Thanks for your help and insight.